# in react-router, it changes url but doesn't navigate?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a button, in the onclick I do transitionTo, the url updates properly but it stays on the same page. I stepped thru transitionTo, it finds the route, does location.push, just never navigates anywhere?

```
var routes = (
    <Route handler={App} path="/">
        <DefaultRoute handler={LandingPage}/>
        <Route name="createEvent" path="createEvent" handler={CreateEvent}/>
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
    </Route>
);
```

React 13.3,
React-Router 13.3

A gist containing relevant files is located here: https://gist.github.com/ocorpening/d178e1907738e19287d0

Comment: Did you try preventing default on the `_onClick()` function?

Comment: I noticed a few buttons... is there a certain one that isn't working or are both of them failing?

Comment: I tried the preventDefault, no help. In the gist if you search for "onclick" it is the first match, right near the top, and the _onclick() it calls is right below that.

Comment: As you're using `Router.HistoryLocation`, have you ensured that the server is set up correctly? Can you manually navigate to the routes by changing the address bar and hitting enter?

Comment: @Owen ever get a solution to this? Having the same issue. Thx!